# How to test libGDX games faster?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, android-virtual-device

Android applications launches slow on AVD - it's unconvinient becasue of frequent changes in your application.
But in this video man launches his game very quickly ( at 7:03): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR88EZEXEQg&list=PLZm85UZQLd2TPXpUJfDEdWTSgszionbJy&index=2
How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Launching it for the very first time is often very slow. There isn't much you can do to make it faster. However, using 'snapshot' instead of 'Use Host GPU' in your emulator settings will make it boot faster. Other than that it is really dependent on your computers hardware. Adding more RAM may speed it up too.

Hope I helped :)